# Helpful flags, no action taken

Tags: discussion, flags, spam, helpful-flags

I recently stumbled upon 4 answers from the same user. All these answers were promoting the same piece of software. The user stated in each of his answers that he is working for the company that created this software.

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61873837/1238965
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62225371/1238965
3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61824926/1238965

I flagged them all as *spam* and they were all deleted.

The one below however, and although my flag was marked as *helpful*, is still there:

4. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61826124/1238965

Why is it so? It's from the same user, promoting the same product. And why was my flag marked as *helpful* and no action taken?

It might be worth noting that this user hasn't posted any answer aside from the above mentioned 4 answers.

Comment: If there is disclosure we normally don't consider it spam. It might be that Jean left that one answer and messaged the user to not do that again. Your flag is still helpful. Keep in mind that a flag isn't a guaranteed way to get a post in state you desire. I've flagged plenty of stuff where a mod took a different approach to resolving the issue.

Comment: @rene spot on. Maybe you should really consider running next election.

Comment: @rene ok I appreciate the feedback. I was just surprised by the fact that all flags were *helpful* and one of them was handled in a different way when all 4 answers looked really "suspicious" to me and in the same way.

Comment: they are all ok, the last offers his affiliation, so no spam in the classical sense. the addresses posted are needed to explain the problem accurately